# PySpark - Does Coalesce(1) Retain the Order of Range Partitioning?

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, sql-order-by, partitioning, coalesce

Looking into the Spark UI and physical plan, I found that `orderBy` is accomplished by `Exchange rangepartitioning(col#0000 ACS NULLS FIRST, 200)` and then `Sort [col#0000 ACS NULLS FIRST], true, 0`.

From what I understand, `rangepartitioning` would define minimum and maximum values for each partition and order the data with column value within the min and max into that partition so as to achieve global ordering.

But now I have 200 partitions and I want to output to a single csv file.  If I do a `repartition(1)`, spark will trigger a shuffle and the ordering will be gone.  However, I tried `coalesce(1)` and it retained the global ordering.  Yet I don't know if it was merely pure luck since `coalesce` does not necessarily decrease number of partitions **and** keep the ordering of partitions.  Does anyone know how to repartition to keep the ordering after `rangepartitioning`?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As you state yourself maintaining order is not part of the coalesce API contract. You you have to choose:

1. collect the ordered dataframe as a list of Row instances and write to csv outside spark
2. write the partitions to individual CSV files with spark and concatenate the partitions with some other tool, e.g. "hadoop dfs getmerge" on the command line.